# Linux Mint 15: Share internet connection with subnet

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I want the following setup:

```
Internet ---- Cable modem
                   |
                   |
                   +--- Router A ---- PC
                   .
                   .
                 (wifi) . . . . [PC, tablet, etc.]
                   .
                   .
            HTPC Linux Mint 15
                   |                 +---- TV
                   |                 |
                   +--- Router B ----+---- PS3
                                     |
                                     +---- Receiver
```

I currently have internet access at HTPC through wifi from Router A.

I want to have internet access for HTPC and devices after Router B.

As of now I don't care that devices after Router B see devices before Router B.

I would like to know how to get internet access for devices after Router B, while keeping internet access of HTPC. HTPC might occasionally pull internet content through OpenVPN.

I tried [Networks Settings] => [Wired] => [Options] => [IPv4 Settings] => [Method:] = "Shared to other computers" on HTPC Linux Mint 15, but it didn't work. I don't know anymore where to look to find a solution, if any.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want HTPC to become the actual router for the stuff currently behind router B.

You should degrade RouterB to a switch, i.e. don't put anything into the uplink port, just put everything (including HTPC) into the normal switch ports of the device.

Then configure HTPC to do the routing and NATting for you.
If you don't want to touch the devices (TV/PS3/...) you give HTPC the same IP than RouterB had before.

A few steps on what to do on HTPC to make it the router:

Turn on ip forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Create the NAT and configure the firewall (ask Google for details)

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

(wlan0 = whatever your wifi interface is called)